# Find a complex substring in another string in Qt

Tags: string, qt, find, substring

I have a substring for example:

```
43ab??12??56??ef
```

`??` are wildcard and the count of `??` is unknown.
I want to check the main string contains this substring or not.
The substring is not unique and it changes always.

Comment: [QRegularExpression](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html) is what you're looking for.

Comment: I know I can use QRegExp. I said the substring is unpredictable